# FutureTask does not seem to interrupt

Tags: java, executorservice

I am making some dummy programs to learn about this java class.
My timed task calls a task which does nothing giving it 3 secs time before interrupting it.
Here's the code:

```
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<>(new
            Callable<Integer>(){
                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    int i =0;
                    while(i<100000){
                        ;
                    }

                    return 0;
                }

    });

    executor.execute(task);
    try {
        task.get(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("Everything was ok");
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException ex){
        boolean result = task.cancel(true); //here i cancel the thread  
        System.out.println("the task has timed out "+result);
    }
```

What happens is that the catch block is executed, but my program keeps running until the thread finishes. It is like task.cancel was not accepted. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your task is compute-bound. It doesn't perform any IO or sleep, and that's when the JVM checks the interrupt flag (any method that throws a `InterruptedException`). Hence your task is uninterruptible.

It's worth reading the [Interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) tutorial. Note:

> What if a thread goes a long time without invoking a method that
>   throws InterruptedException? Then it must periodically invoke
>   Thread.interrupted, which returns true if an interrupt has been
>   received. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    heavyCrunch(inputs[i]);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
        return;
    }
}
```

and also

> The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as
>   the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a
>   thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method
>   Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static
>   isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the
>   interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status
>   flag.

Note that quite often people will write something like:

```
 try {
   // interruptible operation
 }
 catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // do nothing
 }
```

which doesn't reset the interrupted flag. This results in uninterruptible code. See [this JavaSpecialists newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) for more info

Comment: Mmm...problem is that for my true program I need to encapsulate a connection which comes from a jni library. I already made this same program with that connection and it doesn't interrupts either. Is there a way to force the thread to stop?

Comment: See my amended answer above for more info